# Jquery Change value of paragraph

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble updating the `paragraph` value that comes from `ajax request`

```
<div class="comment__text" id="data">
                                    <p>{{ node.text }}</p>
                                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                        <div class="thumb-likes">
                                            <p class="likes">{{ node.likes }}</p>
                                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up hvr-buzz like" data-id="{{ node.id }}"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down hvr-buzz dislike" data-value="{{ node.id }}"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        {% else %}
                                            {{ node.likes }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
```

I have tried the following

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: {
                'like-id': $(this).data('id')
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $(this).closest('.thumb-likes')
                    .find('.likes')
                    .html(response['total_likes']);

            }
        })
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.dislike', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: {
                'dislike-id': $(this).data('value')
            },
            success: function(response) {
                 $(this).closest('.thumb-likes')
                    .find('.likes')
                    .html(response['total_likes']);
            }
        })
    });
```

The value isn't being updated. When i try `$('.likes')` it works but all values are updated simultaneously. If i understand something incorrectly about how to traverse elements, please explain what exactly it is that i'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to bind $(this) to a variable so that it's still available after the ajax call finished:

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function () {
    $this = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        data: {
            'like-id': $(this).data('id')
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // NOTE THIS CHANGE HERE
            $this.closest('.thumb-likes')
                .find('.likes')
                .html(response['total_likes']);
        }
    })
});
```